# Regex: remove scheme unless it's http(s). (capture negative lookbehind pattern)

Tags: php, regex, capture, negative-lookbehind

I'm having a regex blackout here. How do I capture a negative lookbehind pattern again?

I'm trying to remove the scheme (including `://`) of a uri unless it is http/https. I'm half way there (or I thought I was, the pattern below doesn't even compile), but I forgot how to actually capture the negative pattern:

`preg_replace( '~^(?<!https?)://~', '', $uri );`

How can I do this, again?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? That would change the semantics of the URI.

Comment: I'm validating a url, and want to prepend `http://` if the user has not provided this. However, if user provided `ftp://` as a scheme `http://ftp://somedomain.com` will actually return a valid host with `Zend_Uri` (the component I'll be using to validate with), namely: `ftp`. Hope it makes sense, what I'm saying here. :)

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Then why don’t you rather check whether it contains a scheme at all?

Comment: @Gumbo: because if a user provided `https` as a scheme, I don't want to replace it with `http`. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to get at?

Comment: @fireeyedboy: You should not remove anything but add a `http://` only if the URI does not have a scheme at all.

Comment: @Gumbo: Ah yes, I see what you mean now. Hmm, good point yeah. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Gumbo: you've convinced me to change my plan. Out of curiosity though: would it be possible to capture a negative lookbehind pattern? I thought it was, but I'm starting to have my doubts actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#^((?:.(?<!http))+://)#i', '', $uri);
```

Comment: Nice one! Althought Gumbo has convinced me of another approach to reach my goals, this does demonstrate what I was looking for initially. I've tried to incorporate `https` as well with `preg_replace('#^((?:.(?<!http|https))+://)#i', '', $uri);`, and it works. Very nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick thought:

```
preg_replace ('#^((http[s]{0,1}://)|([a-z]+://))#i', '$2', $uri);
```

Comment: You can write `[s]{0,1}` as `s?`.

Comment: I had to look a few times at it to see why this is actually working, but that's pretty clever actually. And it does what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Gumbo: true, I've changed it to this: `'preg_replace('#^(https?://)|([a-z]+://)#i', '$1', $url);` actually.

Comment: @Gumbo I just thought it was more readable this way. Same goes for enclosing parens your eye catches `( | )` more.